# Bluetooth mouse disconnect when Iceweasel loads YouTube... but also does not reconnect

Tags: debian, mouse, bluetooth

The reason this is such an issue is that the mouse also refuses to reconnect automatically.

There is obviously some other process creating the disconnect coincidence though, but it works every time I do the following:

1. Connect BT mouse
2. Open Iceweasel
3. Without using the mouse (it is not moving from this point) open a new tab and go to youtube.com
4. As soon as loaded, try using the mouse and it will be disconnected

Of course the mouse also disconnects at other points but it was uncanny how the above also forces a disconnect. I added it in case someone knows of some connection that could help solve the problem.

I have of course tried a number of other fixes... I even have a script I have set up to reconnect the mouse when it disconnects (as it will not reconnect using the Gnome-Settings bluetooth window).

Finding one of the similar issues online [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177998/bluetooth-mouse-disconnects) I did set the timeout to 0 which did in fact work the best of all the solutions so far. I was able to leave the mouse alone and come back and it will still be connected but after following the steps above it would still disconnect and then go back to the timeout disconnect until restarting the bluetooth service again.

Every disconnect is visible in my logs as:

```
bluetoothd[19123]: g_attrib_unregister: invalid id
```

but it is very often after one of the following:

```
dleyna-server-service[20572]: dLeyna: Exit
```

or while I was using Iceweasel (I've moved to Chrome for the time being):

```
iceweasel.desktop[19712]: Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node
```

Going back to the inability to reconnect, after the mouse disconnects (it's the Razer Orochi if that makes a difference) I cannot just reconnect even if I try force it in the normal GUI based bluetooth settings. I found out the only way it reconnects is through bluetoothctl. While in the bluetoothctl prompt a simple reconnect works but after many variations, the below seems to be the only script that will work in the same way:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'power on\npair D1:A8:11:CC:DB:9A' | bluetoothctl
sleep 1
echo 'trust D1:A8:11:CC:DB:9A' | bluetoothctl
sleep 1
echo 'connect D1:A8:11:CC:DB:9A' | bluetoothctl
```

So yes, that's my predicament... I'm hoping someone might see something here that will lead to the solution but of course feel free to ask for more info and let me know how to get it for you.

Comment: I have a stupid HP equipment that shared the IRQ between video and hard disk by factory default, and had to change it in the BIOS menu boot. I recommend you to investigate wether you are sharing the IRQ between bluetooth and other device.

Comment: I'm on a Lenovo and have had other HW sourced issues so I will do. I would not be surprised...

Comment: I was writing more comments, more convenient to add an answer. Macs and iPhones also suffer from sharing wifi and bluetooth, the problem is well understood.

Comment: Irritating thing is I've now tested my cheap old bluetooth mouse and works perfectly... it's only the new one that has an issue. I'm wondering if there is something Bluetooth 4.0 related that can be causing this.

Comment: Bt4.0 is supposed to save more energy...power management bugs?

Comment: That's what I was thinking but getting nothing coming up in the logs either... anyway, I guess it's not gonna be sorted now but will update this post if I ever do get it sorted... even if a dist upgrade sorts it out.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you describe bluetooth having problems with streaming/heavy Internet usage led me to suspect more of interference/conflict problems than a problem with the operating system.

I will list the possibilities:

- IRQ conflicts between wifi/bluetooth/disk;
- bluetooth/wifi sharing the same port, and having interferences;
- signal interferences in the 2.4GHz range between wifi and bluetooth.

I would investigate those avenues. The solution can range from:

- having to configure different IRQ ports;
- trying a new bluetooth or a wifi pen in the 5GHz range;
- or trying a mouse with an USB dongle that uses other short-range frequency.

Comment: Sadly the IRQ check didn't come up with anything... I wonder if it's just bad drivers for the hardware or that  the hardware is quite old for the BT4.0 support... Luckily, the mouse can also connect by USB so can still use it in the meantime.