# Laggy, hanging, unstable Bluetooth keyboard with Linux only

Tags: linux, keyboard, bluetooth, bluez

I have a laptop with a Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 module, and I had to copy firmware for it from Windows. Also I have a [Samsung Bluetooth Keyboard BKB-10](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/BKB-10USWEGXAR).. Itt worrrks  fine with Windoows 10, but under Ubuntu 16.04 it hangs, disconnects, laggy.
Example of hangs:

```
Likkkkkkkkkke tttttttttttthhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhatt!!!!!!!!!
```

If it disconnects, than just 1 key is pressed for 10-20 seconds, until system understands it is disconnected. But it can print also just 1-10 extra letters without any disconnects.
DDelayys can be from milliseconds to seconds. But sometimes the keyboard works perfectly well under Linux too, and I cannot see any patterns when it does and does not work well.

Because of problems with Bluetooth drivers under Linux for that adapter I thought that drivers are the problem. But then I connected the keyboard to my CyanogenMod 12.1 smartphone, and it is laggy there too! I did not see disconnects, and I not know where to look for logs in Android for Bluetooth disconnects. CM 12.1 use Bluez also, so maybe it is the problem. And again, keyboard can work perfectly well under Linux too. So, I guess it is just Linux, not drivers or hardware problems.
I turned off in tlp all power savings for USB and PCI devices, tried 2 fist solutions from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177998/bluetooth-mouse-disconnects) – nothing.
Also installed Bluez 5.40 (without removing 5.37 Ubuntu version, or I would delete half Ubuntu) and Linux kernel 4.6. Nothing strange appears in logs while keyboard is unstable (laggy and hanging), only if it disconnects.
Another funny thing is that that keyboard is made for Android, but it works well under Windows only.

```
unknown main item tag 0x0
```

appears every time it disconnects.

Note that the above message is bolded in the display below.

```
dmesg
[  440.590111] usbcore: deregistering interface driver btusb
[  444.549055] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[  446.557936] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[  454.551817] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[  454.568686] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[  454.584662] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[  454.584671] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[  455.217642] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0146
[  455.233625] Bluetooth: hci0: Broadcom Bluetooth Device (43142)
[  520.262176] usbcore: deregistering interface driver btusb
[  520.267674] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff88005b287c00 failed to resubmit (2)
[  522.576757] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[  522.581012] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[  522.597023] Bluetooth: hci0: Broadcom Bluetooth Device (43142)
[  522.597032] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0146
[  523.200996] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0146
[  523.217028] Bluetooth: hci0: Broadcom Bluetooth Device (43142)
[  523.350764] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  523.350772] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  523.350779] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  532.571301] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[  532.571308] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[  793.617198] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.0003: unknown main item tag 0x0
[  793.617387] input: Samsung Bluetooth Keyboard BKB-10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:04E8:7021.0003/input/input14
[  793.618079] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.0003: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v7.00 Keyboard [Samsung Bluetooth Keyboard BKB-10] on f8:2f:a8:ed:4d:02
[  978.540391] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.0004: unknown main item tag 0x0
[  978.540524] input: Samsung Bluetooth Keyboard BKB-10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:04E8:7021.0004/input/input15
[  978.542916] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.0004: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v7.00 Keyboard [Samsung Bluetooth Keyboard BKB-10] on f8:2f:a8:ed:4d:02
[ 2922.936556] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.0005: unknown main item tag 0x0
```

```
Jun 14 15:58:53 leonid-Lenovo-G500 acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 16
Jun 14 15:58:53 leonid-Lenovo-G500 bluetoothd[694]: GLib: Source ID 1006 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jun 14 15:58:54 leonid-Lenovo-G500 kernel: [ 7143.006495] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.000F: unknown main item tag 0x0
Jun 14 15:58:54 leonid-Lenovo-G500 kernel: [ 7143.006620] input: Samsung Bluetooth Keyboard BKB-10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:04E8:7021.000F/input/input26
Jun 14 15:58:54 leonid-Lenovo-G500 kernel: [ 7143.007582] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.000F: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v7.00 Keyboard [Samsung Bluetooth Keyboard BKB-10] on f8:2f:a8:ed:4d:02
Jun 14 15:58:54 leonid-Lenovo-G500 upowerd[1464]: (upowerd:1464): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:04E8:7021.000F/power_supply/hid-90:7f:61:10:3c:ab-battery
Jun 14 16:01:53 leonid-Lenovo-G500 acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 16
Jun 14 16:01:53 leonid-Lenovo-G500 bluetoothd[694]: GLib: Source ID 1035 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jun 14 16:01:53 leonid-Lenovo-G500 kernel: [ 7322.201743] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.0010: unknown main item tag 0x0
Jun 14 16:01:53 leonid-Lenovo-G500 kernel: [ 7322.201902] input: Samsung Bluetooth Keyboard BKB-10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:04E8:7021.0010/input/input27
Jun 14 16:01:53 leonid-Lenovo-G500 kernel: [ 7322.202263] hid-generic 0005:04E8:7021.0010: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v7.00 Keyboard [Samsung Bluetooth Keyboard BKB-10] on f8:2f:a8:ed:4d:02
Jun 14 16:01:53 leonid-Lenovo-G500 upowerd[1464]: (upowerd:1464): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:04E8:7021.0010/power_supply/hid-90:7f:61:10:3c:ab-battery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Bluez 5.27 from bluez.org (newer are laggy for me) and lags gone away. Less disconnects also, but i guess it is about ubuntu's work with kernel or smth else.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TLPUI` power management tool (install it if it does not exists on your system).

From its USB menu, you can select `USB_BLACKLIST_BTUSB` to exclude bluetooth devices from USB autosuspend.